# Uncaught Error: Class 'Lime\Courier\Setup\Varien_Db_Ddl_Table' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2\app\code\Lime\Courier\Setup\InstallSchema.php:81

Tags: database, magento-2.1, setup

when i try to install my custom module i got an error saying:

> Installing schema... PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Lime\Courier\Setup\Varien_Db_Ddl_Table' not found in
>   C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\app\code\Lime\Courier\Setup\InstallSchema.php:81
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Lime\Courier\Setup\Varien_Db_Ddl_Table' not found in
>   C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\app\code\Lime\Courier\Setup\InstallSchema.php:81

here's my InstallSchema.php code :

```
<?php


namespace Lime\Courier\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $table_lime_province = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('lime_province'));


        $table_lime_province->addColumn(
            'province_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true,),
            'Entity ID'
        );



        $table_lime_province->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'name'
        );


        $table_lime_city = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('lime_city'));


        $table_lime_city->addColumn(
            'city_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true,),
            'Entity ID'
        );



        $table_lime_city->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'name'
        );



        $table_lime_city->addColumn(
            'province_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [],
            'province_id'
        );

        $table_lime_city->addForeignKey(
             $installer->getFkName('lime_courier/lime_city', 'province_id', 'lime_courier/lime_province','province_id'),
             'province_id',
             $installer->getTable('lime_courier/lime_province'),
             'province_id',
             Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
             Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        );


        $table_lime_subdistrict = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('lime_subdistrict'));


        $table_lime_subdistrict->addColumn(
            'subdistrict_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true,),
            'Entity ID'
        );



        $table_lime_subdistrict->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'name'
        );



        $table_lime_subdistrict->addColumn(
            'city_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [],
            'city_id'
        );

        $table_lime_subdistrict->addForeignKey(
             $installer->getFkName('lime_courier/lime_subdistrict', 'city_id', 'lime_courier/lime_city','city_id'),
             'city_id',
             $installer->getTable('lime_courier/lime_city'),
             'city_id',
             Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
             Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        );


        $table_lime_courier = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('lime_courier'));


        $table_lime_courier->addColumn(
            'courier_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true,),
            'Entity ID'
        );



        $table_lime_courier->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'name'
        );



        $table_lime_courier->addColumn(
            'logo',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'logo'
        );


        $table_lime_courier_service = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('lime_courier_service'));


        $table_lime_courier_service->addColumn(
            'courier_service_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true,),
            'Entity ID'
        );



        $table_lime_courier_service->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'name'
        );



        $table_lime_courier_service->addColumn(
            'service',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'service'
        );



        $table_lime_courier_service->addColumn(
            'courier_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [],
            'courier_id'
        );

        $table_lime_courier_service->addForeignKey(
             $installer->getFkName('lime_courier/lime_courier_service', 'courier_id', 'lime_courier/lime_courier','city_id'),
             'courier_id',
             $installer->getTable('lime_courier/lime_courier'),
             'courier_id',
             Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
             Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        );

        $table_lime_calculated_price = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('lime_calculated_price'));


        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'calculated_price_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true,),
            'Entity ID'
        );



        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'origin_location',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [],
            'origin_location'
        );



        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'city_destination',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [],
            'city_destination'
        );



        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'subs_destination',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [],
            'subs_destination'
        );



        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'courier_service_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [],
            'courier_service_id'
        );



        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'description',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'description'
        );



        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'price',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [],
            'price'
        );



        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'estimation_time',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'estimation_time'
        );



        $table_lime_calculated_price->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            'created_at'
        );



        $table_lime_courier_service->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            'updated_at'
        );


        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table_lime_calculated_price);

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table_lime_courier_service);

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table_lime_courier);

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table_lime_subdistrict);

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table_lime_city);

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table_lime_province);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked below solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$installer->getConnection() in place of $setup->getConnection().`

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace in above code,

Replace

```
   Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
```

With

```
   \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
```

in all places in above code.
Remove var folder and run command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: it works, but after that when i try to run my magento page there is exception log error saying main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists. in C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:406
Stack trace:

Comment: you can just remove var folder first remove module entry from your setup_module table and after you run upgrade command.

Comment: Have you done using above tricks?

Comment: when i try to run upgrade i got the following error `Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists.`

Comment: which error have you faced?

Comment: when i run comannd php bin/magento setup:upgrade got that error, and when i access the magento page same error happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51277/discussion-between-idham-choudry-and-rakesh).